# How to make PHP write asynchronously?

Tags: php, io

Is there a PHP command that write asynchronously (as in I don't care when the data is written and this has very low priority.)

I am hosting 1,300 domains on a server. I know it's a lot. But each takes very little memory, very little CPU, very little bandwidth. The bottleneck is random writes. Too many random writes (and random read). The server is Linux.

I read [here](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2012/06/improving-hdd-performance-linux.html):

> Hence, SYNC-reads and ASYNC-writes are generally a good way to go as
>   they allow the kernel to optimise the order and timing of the
>   underlying I/O requests.
>
> There you go. I bet you now have quite a lot of things to say in your
>   presentation about improving disk-IO. ;-)

Most of the writes are just cache files. I lost nothing if it's wrong once in a while. Basically I want to set up my system so that most read and write goes to the memory and then when I want my server to write data to my disks in sequential block.

I have a huge amount of memory that can be used as cache. In Windows I use supercache to do this and everything loads faster. People there tell that Linux already has block caching. Well, the block caching doesn't work and I am still researching how to make most writes goes to memory first so that data is flushed only ocassionally.

For now, I just want to modify my PHP program so when it writes data it tells the kernel "just write it some times in the future, I can wait and I don't mind."

Is there an option for that? I could use SSD but they are small.

Comment: I believe http://serverfault.com/ will be better place for this question

Comment: If I understand well you want to create a cache system in PHP ?

Comment: Is there a PHP command that write asynchronously (as in I don't care when the data is written and this has very low priority.)

Comment: Have you considered using [redis](http://redis.io/) ?

Answer (score 2):

If most of the write activity is due to caching then I would use either apc or memcached as a a backend to the cache instead of just the filesystem.  Any writes that must be persisted to the file system can then be handled separately without the competing cache io hitting the disk.  The only consideration to make is that your cache is now in memory it will be emptied after a reboot, if that would cause a performance issue you may want to implement a cache warming process.

Most of the major PHP frameworks have memcached and apc  (i.e. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html) )as an available storage adaptor for their caching modules so that would be my first choice.  Failing that you can use the [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) and [apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) extensions directly.

Another option is to look at implementing a queue that you can send the pending writes to.  That queue can then be processed periodically by a scheduled task that performs the writes at an acceptable rate.  I have used [Zend_Queue](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue) in the past for a similar purpose.

Comment: the problem with apc is it's memory only. I need a cache system that is both fast and big. Usually cache fast in memory and write the data fast to disk.